# How to set up a maven debug profile for a maven java project

Tags: java, debugging, maven-3

I am trying to debug a maven cucumber-serenity Java project in Eclipse Photon 2018/12.
Please tell me how I can set up maven debug profile and run so that I can debug through the code by setting breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your needs. If you want to debug tests, just use this profile:

```
<project
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <packaging>...</packaging>

    <repositories>
        ...
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        ...
    </distributionManagement>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>debug</id>
            <properties>
                <maven.surefire.debug>test</maven.surefire.debug>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        ...
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

But if this is not the case, then you could simply configure your Eclipse IDE doing [this](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/dev-extensions-maven-sdk-eclipse-remote-debugging.html).

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is the relative position of <profiles> position with respective to other tags, like <properties>, <dependencies> <plugins>etc.,? I introduced <profiles> section just before closing of the pom file, after<build><plugins> section. Error is non-parseable pom file.

Comment: No man, the `profile` tag is `root`'s child. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Accepted as a solution. But I was pulled in to some thing else. As soon as I get my hands free, I would try it and get back to confirm it is working.